# Easy way to remove link from nav bar if you are on its page with php

Tags: php

Is there an easy way to not echo part of the nav?

**Example** 
"Register" on the nav bar is not needed if you are on register.php Any ideas?

As you can see the else concept is not very effective if they navigate to register.php

```
<?php 
 if(isset($_GET['user_signin'])){
echo("<li><a data-toggle=\"modal\" href=\"#myModal\">Login</a></li>             
<li><a href=\"#\">Email Us</a></li>");
            }else{
            echo("
            <li><a data-toggle=\"modal\" href=\"#myModal\">Login</a></li>               
            <li><a href=\"#\">Email Us</a></li>
            <li><a href=\"#\">Register</a></li>");          
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example.

```
<?php 
 if(isset($_GET['user_signin']))
 {
        echo "<li><a data-toggle=\"modal\" href=\"#myModal\">Login</a></li>             
                <li><a href=\"#\">Email Us</a></li>";
 }
 else
 {
    $currentFile = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
    $parts = explode('/', $currentFile);
    $page = $parts[count($parts) - 1];

    if($page != "login.php" )
        echo "<li><a data-toggle=\"modal\" href=\"#myModal\">Login</a></li>";
    if($page != "login.php" )   
        echo "<li><a data-toggle=\"modal\" href=\"#myModal\">Login</a></li>";
    if($page != "emailus.php" )
        echo "<li><a href=\"#\">Email Us</a></li>";
    if($page != "register.php" )
        echo "<li><a href=\"#\">Register</a></li>";     
 }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Prasad. I am looking up what the explode method does. :)

Answer (score 0):

Simpler way:

```
<?php
// Designate that this page is the Register page by setting variable
$thisPage = 'Register';

if(isset($_GET['user_signin'])){
    echo("<li><a data-toggle=\"modal\" href=\"#myModal\">Login</a></li>             
    <li><a href=\"#\">Email Us</a></li>");
    }
else{
    echo("<li><a data-toggle=\"modal\" href=\"#myModal\">Login</a></li>               
          <li><a href=\"#\">Email Us</a></li>");} 
//If the variable shows that you are NOT on register page, show the link. 
    if($thisPage != 'Register') echo ("<li><a href=\"#\">Register</a></li>");
    ?>
```